# Create many csv files from a main csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with hundreds of rows and I would like to create as many csv files as groups of data from a column. For example I have the below csv:

```
title; data; value
morado; paste1; 002
morado; paste2; 004
rojo; paste1; 008
amarillo; paste1; 112
amarillo; paste2; 002
rojo ; paste2; 010
```

And my groups of data will be the column "title". So the final result will be three differents csv files(morado.csv, rojo.csv and amarillo.csv):

```
title; data; value
morado; paste1; 002
morado; paste2; 004

title; data; value
rojo; paste1; 00
rojo ; paste2; 010

title; data; value
amarillo; paste1; 112
amarillo; paste2; 002
```

What would be the automatic way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum, tutorial service, or code writing service.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. But the reality is that I asked a question to resolve it and that question was not response by a tutorial. I didn´t know if my question had a possible response. So it is difficult to know if this is or not a discussion. Anyway there are colleages voluntered to help me. The definition of this is spend your knowledge  with people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done using a `defaultdict(list)` to accumulate all of the entries containing the same `title`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        data[row[0].strip()].append(row)

for title, entries in data.items():
    with open("{}.csv".format(title), 'wb') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';')
        csv_output.writerow(header)
        csv_output.writerows(entries)
```

Each row is stored in a `defaultdict(list)`. This allows you to append a whole row using the `title` as the key to the dictionary. In your example, you have two groups of rows `rojo` so it is necessary to store all the entries before attempting to start writing them to the file.

The header is stored and used for each of the newly created CSV files. As `data` contains lists of rows, the `writerows()` function can be used to save all of the entries in a single call.